I want a reference for this..Is it obligatory to recite the dua after tashahud and before Salam?
As I listen that if a person does not recite that dua after tashahud and before Salam the person should pray the salah again...said by taus tabiyat
Is it authentic that we have to pray the salah again?

SInce you didn't mention the dua it you keep us guessing and we can't answer properly.
